# Where is config file of ibus stored?

Tags: ibus

I'm wondering where is the config file of ibus stored? I checked `~/.config/ibus`, and there's only a dbus socket. And no ~/.ibus folder available.

Comment: strange. I have it in `~/.config` directory on Fedora17

Comment: Try this command: `find ~ -name ibus`

Comment: @Serge I only have a `/root/.config/ibus/bus/5007c835ce187f9b2248e04c50670a64-unix-0`, what you have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For newer versions see *Koterpillar*'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236817).

---

IIRC `ibus` uses `gconf` to store its settings so you should be able to use either `gconf-editor` or `gconftool` (CLI) to get/set those settings.

Comment: Not on Ubuntu 13.10... I can't find the "ibus" phrase in gconf-editor. Ubuntu 13.10 uses ibus version 1.5.3

Answer (score 12):

As of 1.5.11, IBus uses [dconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dconf). Here is (a snip of) its configuration obtained by: `dconf dump /desktop/ibus/`

```
[general]
use-system-keyboard-layout=false
preload-engines-inited=true
embed-preedit-text=false
use-global-engine=true
version='1.5.11'
engines-order=['xkb:us::eng', 'hangul', 'sunpinyin', 'm17n:ru:kbd']
preload-engines=['xkb:us::eng', 'm17n:ru:kbd', 'hangul', 'sunpinyin']
```

The changes applied by saving the output to a file (`dconf dump /desktop/ibus/ > ibus.dconf`) and then loading it via `dconf load /desktop/ibus/ < ibus.dconf`) have been applied *without a restart* of IBus.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the same thing elsewhere, that the configuration is stored in `gconf`, and that you can edit that with command line tools.
But when I try that, it doesn't seem to have any effect.  I am on Suse Linux 12.3.

To find out what to change, I first did a recursive-list of `gconf` and saved it to a file:

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-list / > beforeConfig.txt
```

Then I started `ibus-setup`, and did 'Select an Input Method', Japanese, Anthy, Add, Close.

Then I did another recursive-list:

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-list / > afterConfig.txt
```

Then I did a diff on the two files and saw that the only difference was with preload engines:

```
preload_engines = []

     vs.

preload_engines = [anthy]
```

And that it was under `/desktop/ibus/general`
So I figured that starting over with ibus unconfigured, I could do the following to configure it:

```
gconftool-2 --set /desktop/ibus/general/preload_engines --type string "[anthy]"
```

After that, I did another recursive-list, and found it identical to the `afterConfig.txt` one.
But then if I start `ibus-setup`, it does not show any Input methods configured.  And it does not work as if it is configured.

So is the configuration also stored somewhere else besides `gconf`?  Someplace that actually matters?
Or am I doing something wrong when setting the `preload_engines` value?

I also tried it on Suse Linux 12.1, with the same results, except a somewhat different value for
that key:

```
preload_engines = [anthy,m17n:ko:han2]
```