# How to input Japanese in Debian?

Tags: debian, keyboard, keyboard-layout, deb

I have a serious issue in inputting Japanese in Debian distribution via xterm I configured the following file:

```
 /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
```

with the following:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "keyboard-all"
    Driver "evdev"
    Option "XkbLayout" "us,it,jp"
    Option "XkbOptions" "grp:shift_toggle"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
EndSection
```

which would enable 3 input languages: English Italian and Japanese from the keyboard when running xterm or anything similar I can input English and Italian but not Japanese. I tried installing a lot of Japanese font packages but nothing worked for me. Can any one help me with this issue, because I am almost trying to make this work for more than one week! what is so special in Japanese language that it couldn't be inputted via the keyboard?!

I don't want to install any thing that needs any GUI interaction only scripting.

thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I do not speak Japanese. This answer is solely based on rough ideas on East Asian languages that deals with kanji, specifically the two written Mandarin Chinese standards.*

Japanese support is far more than keyboard layouts – you get two phonetic writing systems (*kana*, both of which needs ~50+ glyphs), and three thousand-ish ideographs (*kanji*) that are usually indexed by searching phonetic sequences. There is no way to have a single keyboard layout to handle this much characters (unless you decide to go with [Google's 2010 April Fool prank](https://japan.googleblog.com/2010/04/google.html)), so you have to use an imput method to help you.

Debian's [guide on Japanese Environment](https://wiki.debian.org/JapaneseEnvironmentE) suggests using `ibus-mozc` for input. You will need to relogin to X after `sudo apt install ibus-mozc`, and you should then set up ibus to use the mozc input method. You should be able to do it in command line by playing with `dconf`: [where is config file of ibus stored?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49452/where-is-config-file-of-ibus-stored)

For TTY input, use the framebuffer terminal [`ibus-fbterm`](https://github.com/fujiwarat/ibus-fbterm). You usually need huge kernel font patches for displaying kanji natively in TTY, but fbterm does the job for you in framebuffer.

I am not entirely sure about how the IM works, so you may need to read this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_input_methods) for some ideas on using it.

Comment: thanks for your help and reply, I appreciate it. I will be digging into it but one question can all this configurations be done only via scripting without any GUI interaction?!

Comment: @flashDisk ibus stores its config in dconf, so it should be possible if you follow that question I linked to.